# How to increment a numeric distance based on grouping in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In R, given a data frame with the first column as a grouping variable and the second column (id) as an incrementing numeric vector, how can we keep group id with 1 gap in `id`?
For example, if we have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3), rep('c', 3)), 
                 id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

we want to get a new id column as:

```
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11
```

```
> df_new
   group id
1      a  1
2      a  2
3      a  3
4      b  5
5      b  6
6      b  7
7      c  9
8      c 10
9      c 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table::rleid()` or `dplyr::consecutive_id()` (requires dplyr version >= 1.1.0) to get blocks of id, then manipulate there.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(id2 = rleid(group) + id - 1)

  group id id2
1     a  1   1
2     a  2   2
3     a  3   3
4     b  4   5
5     b  5   6
6     b  6   7
7     c  7   9
8     c  8  10
9     c  9  11
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cur_group_id` while grouping by *group*

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0, otherwise use group_by

df %>% 
  mutate(id = id + cur_group_id() - 1, .by = group)
  group id
1     a  1
2     a  2
3     a  3
4     b  5
5     b  6
6     b  7
7     c  9
8     c 10
9     c 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
df$id <- with(df, with(rle(group), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)) + id - 1)
df$id
[1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  9 10 11
```